# C# List implementation

Tags: c#, data-structures

I am not very good at data structures but I wanna  try to implement in C# List class with method Add that's the only method that I need and I can't figure it out what to do next I only have this piece of code

```
public class myList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public T[] items;
        public int size;

        public myList()
        {

            items = new T[0];
        }
        public myList(int dim)
        {
            items = new T[dim];
        }


        public new void Add(T item)
        {
            items[size++] = item;

        }
    }
```

I am also use inheritance to List because I don't want to implement other things(interfaces).With this code that I have something is missing when I am trying to see what I add to the list(foreach) I can't see nothing. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Why are you inheriting from `List<T>` if you're going to shadow it's actual functionality? You should inherit from `IList<T>`.

Comment: On top of the issue of inheritance instead of implementing an interface, you never attempt to resize your array.

Comment: If you need just standard functionality, you should use standard List

Comment: And before you `size++` you'll have to make sure there is room to spare.

Answer (score 9):

You're inheriting from `List<T>`:

```
public class myList<T> : List<T>
```

And the overriding the `Add(T item)` method with your own implementation:

```
public new void Add(T item)
```

And that's *all you're overriding*.  So when you try to *read* from your object, you're using the implementations that are on `List<T>`.  But nothing was ever added to *that* implementation, because your override intervened.  As far as that parent class' implementation is concerned, *nothing was ever added to it*.

Either override everything you need to use, or don't use that base class.  Perhaps instead you want to implement the *interface*:

```
public class myList<T> : IList<T>
```

This would force you to provide implementations for the functionality needed by that interface.  Otherwise what you have is two half-implementations of a list which don't know anything about each other.  Some functionality goes to one of them, other functionality to another.

Comment: Yes it makes sense now thanks...I'll just go straight my teacher said he don't want me to use class List implemented so he told me to implement for myself but I couldn't find any useful resource on internet all I founded was about Linked Lists and I need to use generic lists because i build a game Battleships and i use lists for various data.That's why i used new keyword because i wanted to have my own version of Add function...and i didn't want to inherit from interfaces because of implementation ..i want to keep it simple and straight...